# Can't make wmode: 'transparent' work on sIFR 3

Tags: javascript, css, flash, sifr

I've been trying to use sIFR to change some text in my webpage. It works fine until I try to get it to use a transparent canvas. The code I'm using is as follow. I have no idea to fix it. I've seen a lot of people make this questions about wmode: 'transparent' and it all seems to work but mine. Can someone give me a hand???

Without the wmode: 'transparent' property it works fine. When I include the property it doesn't activate sIFR and we get the page as the normal HTML.

sIFR.replace(myriadPro, {
  selector: '#title1,#title3,#title5,#title7,#title9,#title11,#title13,#title15,#title17,#title19',
  css: [ '.sIFR-root {background-color:none;font-size:45px;visibility:visible;text-decoration:none;color:#4C4843;cursor:pointer;}' ],
  wmode: 'transparent'
});

Answer (score 1):

wmode: 'transparent',
  transparent: 'true'

is what I used and it worked. I placed in the sifr-config.js after the css: {...},

Comment: and background-color: transparent; in the css:{...} obj

Answer (score 0):

Might have something to do with that odd `background-color:none` property in the CSS.

Comment: I've tried to change and put a color and it didn't work.
I've tried to take it off and it didn't work either!
I've tried to put it transparent and no luck.

Besides the documentation says its recommended to put a background-color

Comment: Yes, but not to `none`.

An example page would help.

Comment: Not too sure. I have `background-color: none` in some of my own sIFR text. Have had no problem with it so far.

Answer (score 0):

Add a comma after transparent.

Comment: Why? There is no need. `wmode: 'transparent'})` works fine for me.